# Matlab numerical fixed point method wrong solution

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I have a following code

```
function y = fixedpoint(g,p0,to1,N)
%g - function
%p0 - starting point
%to1 - max error
%N - no. of iterations

for k=1:N
    p = feval(g,p0);
    abserr = abs(p-p0);
    relerr = abserr/(abs(p)+eps);
    if (abserr<to1) && (relerr<to1)
        break
    end
    p0 = p;
end

if (k==N)
    disp('No fixed point')
end

y = p;
```

using which I want to find solution for `x = f(x)`. It works correctly when I'm using it with a simple function like `x^2 - 2`, but when using it with `tan(x^3)` I get very strange solution.

How can I explain this? Is there a problem with the code, or is this about some properties of `tan(x)` function?

Example of input data with strange answer:

```
y = @(x) tan(x^3);
fixedpoint (y,1,1e-15,1000)
```

Answer I get is `5.1310e-271`

Comment: Give and example of input data for which the a "very strange solution is obtained", so that we can reproduce your case

Comment: What do you find strange about this? It's giving you a fixed point of the function, namely `0`. You have been lucky that it does at least converge; for other functions it might not :-)

Comment: It seems the you get the correct answer here. The answer you get is extremely close to 0 which is indeed a true root to `tan(x^3)`

Comment: I just thought my algorithm will find zero of the function nearest to the starting point. Isn't that a way it works?

Comment: @MateuszKowalski It doesn't necessarily find the zero nearest to the starting point, because each "jump" may take it close to some other zero. As I said, this isn't even guaranteed to converge to a zero (for general functions)